# Google wrongly choose which page is AMP

Tags: amp-html

google webmaster console gives me errors like this for all my amp pages:
Invalid CSS stylesheet, 
AMP markup missing or incorrect, 
Prohibited HTML Tag with AMP equivalent
[image: photo showing issues]

as I checked what the console is looking at I've found out it's looking at normal page, not the amp version. My links are like aaa.com/amp/smth/abc
and normal page is aaa.com/smth/abc
on normal page I have the link in header the one with amphtml, on the amp version I have canonical link.

Anyone had similiar problem?

Oh and I'm using such schema.org data (maybe it has some magic properties). [image]

Comment: its hard to say without actually seeing it. Only reason I can think of is you did the `amphtml` and `canonical` link wrong, put the `<html amp>` attribute  on the normal page or you just misread the search console info. It will still visit the full page, but shouldn't be thinking the full page is AMP without some error there to confuse it,

Comment: Thank you so much for replying to my question.
Here are the links:
https://taimingu.com/amp/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941
https://taimingu.com/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941

Comment: @FireLancer can you please look at links?

Answer (score 0):

When visiting https://taimingu.com/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941 I see:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" amp="" data-react-helmet="lang,amp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ...
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" data-react-helmet="true">
    ...
    <link rel="amphtml" href="https://taimingu.com/amp/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941">
    ...
```

And following https://taimingu.com/amp/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941 I see:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
  ...
  <link rel="canonical" href="https://taimingu.com/job/designer-webmobile-app-59776518b7b5c71627860941">
```

So the actual `link` tags look correct to me, but you have that `amp=""` there in the main version, even though that page is not AMP.

Even though Chrome renders the full page correctly, I suspect the search bot on the other hand is getting confused and thinking your full page is AMP, and then getting confused when it finds content AMP does not allow (because its not an AMP page at all).

Removing that attribute and getting Google to recrawl the main page I think will solve it. It will treat it as a full featured mobile page then crawl the amp version from the `link` seperately.